# How can I pull only Xth and Nth item from my huge list?

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
text =  soup.find('p').getText().split()
# I want to print only every 8th and 23th item

print text
print len(text)
```

and there is an output containing a huge list.

```
[u'15', u'Jan', u'Moscow', u'(DME)', u'Geneva', u'(GVA)', u'A319',...
2355
```

In my case I need to get only **8th and 23rd item**, I would love to use list comprehension, but I am not sure how to do it.
would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: post url or html code

Comment: Do you expect two items (nr 8 and 23) or many more items (every 8th and 23rd item**s**)?

Comment: @宏杰李 r = requests.get('http://therewithu.com/flights/') I am testing something, so it looks just plain text from a web-site page

Comment: @HannesOvrén every 8th and 23rd :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slices with steps, in the format of `text[index-1::index]`:

```
print(text[7::8] + text[22::23])
```

That would mean (humanly), start from the 8th item and collect another one every 8 items. Same goes for 23.

Comment: This will not provide the requested output.

Comment: @DeepSpace "I want to print only every 8th and 23th item" from OP

Comment: I see. OPs in-code comment and question-body are mismatching. "I want to print only every 8th and 23th item" compared to "In my case I need to get only 8th and 23rd item,".

Comment: I understood it as missing `s`, "In my case I need to get only 8th and 23rd items" which would be logical

Comment: sorry my bad, I meant every 8 and 23rd items

Comment: the OP give the url and he split the text in wrong way. why don't you take look at the source code and use more elegant way to parse this data?

Comment: @宏杰李 the question was about how to get certain slices, not about how to make his code elegant. adding additional information is directed to comments

Comment: @Uriel Eli why you try to pull data from a wrong source data? and the OP is wrong at the beginning, you just make him worse.

Comment: I pull no data out of no source. I answered about getting elements from list, which is what OP asked. If OP claims he get the right list using his code, I believe him and use the data he gives to answer him.

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'http://therewithu.com/flights/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
lines = soup.find(class_="entry-content").p.text.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    l = line.strip().split('\t')
    print(l)
```

out:

```
['15 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A319 (HB-IPT)', '3:15', '4:30 PM', '5:16 PM', '6:20 PM']
['14 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-IJN)', '3:14', '4:30 PM', '5:13 PM', '6:20 PM']
['13 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-JLR)', '3:19', '4:30 PM', '5:59 PM', '6:20 PM']
['12 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-IJH)', '3:26', '4:30 PM', '4:54 PM', '6:20 PM']
['11 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-IJN)', '3:15', '4:30 PM', '4:51 PM', '6:20 PM']
['10 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-JLQ)', '3:03', '4:30 PM', '6:17 PM', '6:20 PM']
['09 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-JLS)', '3:14', '4:30 PM', '5:17 PM', '6:20 PM']
['08 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-JLS)', '3:03', '4:30 PM', '5:48 PM', '6:20 PM']
['07 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-JLQ)', '3:14', '4:30 PM', '5:12 PM', '6:20 PM']
['06 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-IJQ)', '3:08', '4:30 PM', '5:20 PM', '6:20 PM']
['05 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-IJE)', '3:09', '4:30 PM', '5:24 PM', '6:20 PM']
['04 Jan', 'Moscow (DME)', 'Geneva (GVA)', 'A320 (HB-IJD)', '3:16', '4:30 PM', '5:16 PM', '6:20 PM']
```

You split wrong line, you should split each entry into a list, then use index to get the info you need.

Comment: Man, you just made my life so much easier.
I am just starting coding and that looks super clean !!
Thanks a ton !!!! From that it's a lot easier I believe ! man thanks !!
Unfortunately can not upvote yet, but man u saved me !

Comment: how does this answers the question?

Comment: In my case I had to change lxml to parser line 5, but works very well anyways.
Thanks a ton !

Comment: @UrielEli is right tbh, but idk how to thank you, can't even upvote.
feel like a d**k but i do appreciate a ton !